# Removed a column, Rails still wants to write on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently I removed a column `abc` from one of my tables using `rake db:migrate`, `remove_column` on `self.up`. The column has been successfully removed.

While I try to add an entry to the table, I have this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'abc' in 'field list': 
INSERT INTO...
```

It was trying to write on that column, though it doesn't exist anymore. I have checked all my models and confirmed `abc` doesn't exist anymore. Also checked `schema.rb` and `abc` has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change something like this on production, you must reload the application... If you are using Phusion Passenger, you do it by running:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be referring to 'abc' column where ever you are trying to add an entry to the table. You need to remove the reference as the column has been removed.

Thanks......

Comment: I've already checked my code, doing an app-wide search. No association. But it worked after an Apache reload. It's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after reloading Apache. Is this actually the correct way?

Comment: If you are not in development mode, for changes like these (any changes for that matter), you would need to restart Apache/Nginx.